Angular 19 RenderMode Error: “The '*/**' server route does not match the Angular routing configuration...”
I’m migrating an Angular 18 project to Angular 19. Previously, I used a routes.txt file for server prerendering (SSG), and it worked fine. Now, with Angular 19, I switched to the RenderMode (Hybrid Rendering) configuration in app.routes.server.ts, but I’m facing the following problem:
[ERROR] The 'archives/*' server route does not match any routes defined in the Angular routing configuration...

I get this message for several routes that used to work normally in SSR/SSG. In my app.routes.ts, there is literally no 'archives/*' path. Instead, I have something like:
// app.routes.ts
import { Routes, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

// 1) The custom matcher:
export function friendlyUrlMatcher_Or_SumarioIdUrlMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  // The idea is to match either a user-friendly slug
  // (e.g. "my-article-slug") or a numeric ID (e.g. "123")
  const regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{3,}(-[a-zA-Z]{3,})+$/; // e.g.: "my-friendly-url"
  const numericRegex = /^[1-9][0-9]{0,4}$/;       // e.g.: "123"
  
  if (url.length >= 1 && (regex.test(url[url.length - 1].path) || numericRegex.test(url[url.length - 1].path))) {
    return {
      consumed: url,
      posParams: {
        sumarioId: url[0], // or url[url.length - 1]
      },
    };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

// 2) The archives route with sub-routes:
export const routes: Routes = [
  // ... other routes ...
  {
    path: 'archives',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'page/:page',
        // loadComponent, canActivate, etc.
      },
      {
        path: 'vol/:vol',
        // loadComponent, canActivate, etc.
      },
      {
        path: ':sumarioId/:pathParam',
        // loadComponent, etc.
      },
      {
        // This uses the custom matcher:
        matcher: friendlyUrlMatcher_Or_SumarioIdUrlMatcher,
        // loadComponent, canActivate, etc.
      },
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'page/1',
      },
    ],
  },
  // ... other routes ...
];

But in app.routes.server.ts, I tried something like:
// app.routes.server.ts
import { RenderMode, ServerRoute } from '@angular/ssr';

export const serverRoutes: ServerRoute[] = [
  {
    path: 'archives/:id',
    renderMode: RenderMode.Prerender,
    async getPrerenderParams() {
      // ...
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'archives/**',
    renderMode: RenderMode.Server,
  },
  // other routes...
];

Then I get the error that 'archives/*' or 'archives/**' doesn’t match anything defined in the Angular routing. Under Angular 18, I just listed the routes in routes.txt and did the prerender build without issues. Now, as far as I understand, Angular 19 requires a literal match on both the client and server side. I don’t really want to remove the matcher or create an “alias” route for each case, since that would require a larger refactor.
Question: Has anyone faced a similar situation and found a solution without replacing the matcher with a literal path or creating a route alias? Is there any way to keep the matcher working and still do SSR/SSG without that “route not found” error in app.routes.server.ts?
